# How do i clear view bag name from application memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I stored a result set in a viewdata["Clientgroup"], and assigning the viewdata["Clientgroup"] to a drop downlist,

```
var title = (from c in db.Titles select c.TitleName).Distinct().ToList();
        var titleList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var rel in title)
        {
            var con = new SelectListItem();
            con.Text = rel;
            con.Value = rel;
            titleList.Add(con);
        }
        ViewData["ClientGroup"] = titleList;


 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientGroup, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ClientGroupItems"], "---Select---", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

i later change the viewbag name to:

```
ViewData["ClientGroupItems"] = titleList;
```

now, whenever i run the application it throws exception:

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'ClientGroup' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

i have done some research on this, still could not resolve it, please does anyone know how to handle this?

Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Corporate(CorporateViewModel corporate)
    {

        try
        {
            var cust = new Customer()
            {
                ClientType = Session["ClientType"].ToString(),
                ClientId = corporate.ClientId,
                ClientGroup = corporate.ClientGroup,
                OrgName = corporate.OrgName,
                Branch = corporate.Branch,
                RegOffice = corporate.RegOffice,

            };
            db.Customers.Add(cust);
            db.SaveChanges();



            var temCt = Session["clientType"];

            var clientGroup = (from ct in db.ClientTypes
                               join cg in db.ClientGroups
                                   on ct.RowId equals cg.ClientTypeId

                               where ct.TypeName == temCt.ToString()
                               select cg.GroupName).ToList();

            var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach(var t in clientGroup)
            {
                var s = new SelectListItem();

                s.Text = t;
                s.Value = t;

                items.Add(s);
            }
            ViewData["ClientGroupItems"] = items;

            ModelState.AddModelError("success", "Record created successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            var temCt = Session["clientType"];

            var clientGroup = (from ct in db.ClientTypes
                join cg in db.ClientGroups
                    on ct.RowId equals cg.ClientTypeId

                where ct.TypeName == temCt.ToString()
                select cg.GroupName).ToList();

            var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var t in clientGroup)
            {
                var s = new SelectListItem();

                s.Text = t;
                s.Value = t;

                items.Add(s);
            }
            ViewData["ClientGroupItems"] = items;
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }

        return View(corporate);
    }
```

Comment: Exception text is self-explanatory. You have `ViewData[yourKey]` of type `string`, but trying to cast it to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: First your using `ViewData` (not `ViewBag`). The error occurs because `ViewData["ClientGroupItems"]` is `null` when you render the view. Probably because you return the view in the POST method and have not reassigned a value to `ViewData["ClientGroupItems"]`

Comment: yes, it is viewdata, the error only occurs in the post method(i.e. whenever i want to submit the record) how can i make it not to be null and why is it still seeing the old key in the error?

Comment: Then reassign it before you return the view - just as you did in the GET method

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Its not irrelevant. OP is using the value of `ViewData["ClientGroupItems"]` as the `SelectList` in the `DropDownListFor()` method, but if that value is `null` (which it is because OP did not assign it in the POST method before returning the view), then the fallback of the helper is to use the first parameter (the value of property `ClientGroup`) as the `SelectList` - but its not typeof `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` hence the exception. But the code is incomplete because OP has not shown the POST method :)

Comment: @stephen, here is the post method: